# Add padding if screen is wider than 900px

Tags: html, css, width, media-queries, padding

I am trying to make my website appear differently on different screens.

I am using a media query in my CSS to change certain elements. However, I seem to be doing something wrong, since the browser is doing exactly opposite of what I want it to.

I want to add padding to my content element (a single div with class `content`) only if the screen is wide enough to fit it. In my case, I want the padding to be added only if the screen is wider than 1000px.

This is what I have now:

```
.content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 990px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
}
@media (max-width:1000px) {
    .content{
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help here? I know this is probably something really simple, but I haven't used these media queries a lot before, so I don't know all the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that code you provided is working, at least for me. But the problem might be that 5px is to small to notice.

Try increasing it to 20px or 50px to see if its working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use '@media only screen and()'. Try:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1000px) {
    .content{
    padding:0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was working. The browser was caching the old CSS, so the changes did not show. I cleared the cache (Ctrl+F5) and it worked.